# Sending a form refreshes page and not posting to MongoDb Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

**Problem 1:**  Content not showing after the last Else statement in **index.jsx** file  for the form, fixing it would be deleting the last Else statement but this leads to another problem.

**Problem 2:** After pressing the Send Button in the mail form, the page refreshes but nothing shows in either database nor the message that Mail Successfully sent.

i hope someone can help me. **No Error Messages in console**

Here's all the files:
**index.jsx(mail):**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as mailActions from "../../store/actions/mail";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../Loader";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import SendIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Send";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import "./style.css";

class CreateMail extends Component {
  state = {
    createMail: false,
  };

  createMailHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        createMail: !prevState.createMail,
      };
    });
  };
  render() {
    let content;

    if (this.props.loading) {
      content = <Loader />;
    } else if (this.props.error) {
      content = (
        <div>
          {this.props.errorMessages.map((error, i) => (
            <p key={i}>{error}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.props.mailSent) {
      content = <p>Mail sent successfully!</p>;
    } else {
      content = (
        <form className="createMailForm">
          <div className="formControl">
            <TextField
              id="receiver"
              label="Receiver"
              type="text"
              name="receiver"
              placeholder="Username of receiver"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="formControl">
            <TextField
              label="Subject"
              type="text"
              name="subject"
              placeholder="Subject"
              id="subject"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="formControl">
            <TextField id="body" label="Body of the Mail" multiline rows={6} />
          </div>
          <button className="createMailSendBtn">
            <SendIcon />
          </button>
        </form>
      );
    }
    return (
      <>
        <div className="createMailContainer" onClick={this.createMailHandler}>
          <button className="createMailCreateBtn">
            <AddIcon
              className={`${
                this.state.createMail ? "createMailCreateBtn--close" : ""
              }`}
            />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div
          className={`createMailFormContainer ${
            this.state.createMail
              ? "formContainer--visible"
              : "formContainer--hidden"
          }`}
        >
          {content}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    ...state.mail,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    mailInit: (mailObj) => dispatch(mailActions.mailInit(mailObj)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateMail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Problem 2** is because of this:

```
<form className="createMailForm">
```

you have to pass a submit handler method here and that method must hold the form submit like:

```
<form className="createMailForm" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
```

and

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Now perform your action here like make api call or call some action etc
}
```